# Bootstrap Glyphicon is not wroking

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement Bootstrap glyphicon-plus and glyphicon-minus. But when I click on `glyphicon-plus`, it does not hit the control.I think I am doing something wrong in JQuery code. Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

//My JavaScript

```
  $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).closest('div#aa').prev("a").find("span.glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).closest('div#aa').prev("a").find("span.glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    });
```

//View Code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Search            
                </div>
                <div id="aa" class="panel-body">

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA, new {@class = "form-control"})

                    <a id="advance" href="#" class="control-label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>                     
                </div>
            </div>   


        <div id="advancedcontainer" class="collapse">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-body">                
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, "Start Date")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 155px", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.StartDate) })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Distance)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Distance, Model.DistanceOptions, "--Please Select--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 150px;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Distance)

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `closest('div#aa')`. `closest` will find parent.

`.collapse` and `panel panel-default` are the siblings.

Should be `$(this).parent().find('#advance span')` to find the parent first, and then you will find span.

Comment: I did something like this `$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        
        $(this).parent().find('#advance a').removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('#advance a').removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    });`

Comment: But the sign is not changing

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my post. Should be `$(this).parent().find('#advance span')`